# How can I determine what type of resistor, transistor and, diode I need?

Tags: design

I'm trying to build the following circuit

[image]

Given my solenoid draws 1.4A, how do I determine what type of resistor, transistor, and diode I should use?  What if I were to change my power to 9V?  I'd prefer to see answers accompanied by the math so I can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you this, but your circuit (as shown) won't work.

For a transistor to work as a switch (transistor dropping less than about 1/2 volt), you should design for a base current about 1/10 to 1/20 the collector current. In your case, this requires 70 to 140 mA, and there is no GPIO pin which will handle that.

So you have a choice: use a Darlington or a MOSFET. If you choose a Darlington, you can assume a gain in the vicinity of 100, for a base current around 1 to 1.5 mA. If your GPIO pin is 5 volt, this will require a base resistor of about $$R = \frac{5-1.4}{.001\text{ to }.0015} = 2.4\text{ k to } 3.6\text{ k}.$$ and allowing for the GPIO voltage being somewhat less than a nominal 5 volts suggests something like 2k.

If you use a MOSFET, you'll need to be careful about threshold voltage. If your GPIO has a 3.3 volt high level, a lot of MOSFETs are not guaranteed to turn on at this gate voltage, so you need to pay close attention to the Vgs(th) voltage, which must have a maximum value less than your minimum GPIO voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram shows an NPN transistor. If you choose an NPN transistor, then you choose your base resistor based on the GPIO voltage, the supply voltage, the \$\beta\$ of the transistor, and the desired load current (1.4A) (hint: you can solve this easily with the basic model of a BJT).

However, a MOSFET is more appropriate in this situation, in which case the *gate* resistor (MOSFETs don't have bases) is simply to prevent fast edges from ringing, and can be pretty much anything in the 1k-100kΩ range. Additionally, you might want a pull-down resistor on the gate to ensure that it goes to a predictable state if the device driving your GPIO pin is disconnected.

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110574/how-to-choose-a-flyback-diode-for-a-relay) will help you with flyback diode selection. Basically, you need a diode that can handle at least 1.4A. However, it doesn't need to handle this for very long, which makes choosing your diode much easier.

Comment: With a MOSFET would I need a resistor on the gate?  I'm trying to release a drop of water so I need very fast control over the solenoid

Comment: As I said, with a MOSFET, the gate resistor is not necessary to limit current, but only to control slew rate/ringing. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68748/question-about-mosfet-gate-resistor) is a more complete answer. In your application, the MOSFET is not the limiting factor, the mechanical mass of the solenoid is going to be the slowest thing in the system.

Comment: Assuming I stick with a NPN, the load would be 12.5V/1.4A = 8.57 Ohms?.  I'm kina in the same situation as [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29029/choosing-the-right-transistor-for-a-switching-circuit) but I don't have any parts in my kit.

Comment: As for your hint, are you talking about IC/B

Comment: If you need fast turn-off of the solenoid, you should add a zener diode in series with the flywheel diode -- ~ 40 V would work. This zener will make the solenoid current decay much faster and release the solenoid. A R on the FET gate helps with possible ringing; unless it is many Mohm, it won't have any appreciable effect on the solenoid speed.