# Attempting to switch on and off a 4.5 V solenoid with a transistor using a push button to control input

Tags: transistors, batteries, solenoid, button

I have a very simple setup powered by a 9 V battery. The lock solenoid when connected directly to the battery works great.

I have built a test circuit using a push button and a transistor in an attempt to make it so that when I press the button down the lock solenoid will power up. This circuit works fine with an LED, but does nothing at all when I swap the LED for the lock solenoid. I have tested this with a DC motor and lock solenoid. Both the motor and solenoid are 4.5 V and work when directly connected to the battery, but not when replacing the LED in the circuit. I will attach some photos of the circuit.

I have been messing with this for days with no progress. My ultimate goal is to control this solenoid with an Arduino Nano, but I could not get that working so I am trying to get it working with the push button acting as the Nano IO signal before I move further with the microcontroller.

Any advice at all would be appreciated, I am still very new to all this.

Circuit photos attached below:

[image: Solenoid Circuit]

[image: Led Circuit]

[image: Crude Schematic]

Comment: Post your schematic.

Comment: Note the statement "it works" does not mean "it is correct". So, the LED burns does not mean the circuit is as it should be. The circuit is missing (current limiting) resistors and the switched current seems to be running through the button (whic shouldn't as that is the reason to use a transistor+button instead of only a button). Please add the schematic you used or provide the transistor type and pinout

Comment: Looks like the switch is in series with the LED or solenoid, rather than controlling the transistor.  Please show a schematic of your circuit, and include the transistor part number.

Comment: The photos of the circuits are all I have. I have not drawn a schematic. I am certainly a noob to all of this, but I tried it with multiple different resistor with the same outcomes.  I just do not understand how the led could work, but not the solenoid once the led is in place. Even though the power supply will directly power either one of them.

Comment: 58050 NPN transistor I think is correct

Comment: I have also switched that out with a IRF520N Transistor, but it gives me the same results. It will work with an led, but not a motor or solenoid.

Comment: PLEASE draw a schematic so you, and we, know how things are really connected in your circuit.  As I said in a previous comment, it appears that you have the switch in series with the LED or solenoid, rather than controlling the transistor which in turn controls the LED or solenoid.

Comment: I have added a very crudel drawn schematic. This is my first schematic ever, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Why don't you use the built in schematic editor? How can we know which pin of your transistor serves which function? Btw it is a little miracle that your circuit produces blue light without magic blue smoke.

Comment: On your breadboard, you have a red wire from one end of the LED to one terminal of the switch, with no other connections to those points.  That is not what your schematic shows.  The other terminal of the button does not appear to be connected to the negative terminal of the battery.  The schematic you drew does not match the circuit on the breadboard.

Comment: I did not realize there was a built in schematic editor. I will check it out.

Comment: You were right. I should have the other terminal of the button to the negative and the other terminal was going to the led instead of the transistor. It is functioning now. I have lost a lot of sleep over this. I know it is simple for you guys, but it is still very new to me. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any resistors in your circuit, only a transistor in the TO-92. So probably your transistor is MOSFET and its Ron is too high. 
 Try another transistor with lower Ron (1..50mΩ).
 LED requires just few mA to illuminate unlike the solenoid which requires much higher current to turn on.

Comment: I have added a very crudel drawn schematic. This is my first schematic ever, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Very similar question is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210437/how-can-i-determine-what-type-of-resistor-transistor-and-diode-i-need

Comment: Yeah... it's unclear what kind of transistor it is, or how much current he's expecting to draw through the solenoid.